# CqlEngine - sync_table() KeyError: 'cqlengine'

Tags: python, python-2.7, cassandra-2.0, cqlengine

I am just starting to work with Cassandra in python using cqlengine.

I tried following this [link](https://cqlengine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#getting-started) and tried ran this script:

```
from cqlengine import columns
from cqlengine import Model
from cqlengine import connection

from cqlengine.management import sync_table

import uuid


class ExampleModel(Model):
    example_id = columns.UUID(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    example_type = columns.Integer(index=True)
    created_at = columns.DateTime()
    description = columns.Text(required=False)


connection.setup(['127.0.0.1'], 'cqlengine')

sync_table(ExampleModel)
```

But it throws up this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/zopper/Desktop/django-cassandra/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cqlengine/management.py", line 92, in sync_table
    keyspace = cluster.metadata.keyspaces[ks_name]
KeyError: 'cqlengine'
```

My `pip freeze` is:

```
Django==1.7.3
argparse==1.2.1
blist==1.3.6
cassandra-driver==2.1.3
cqlengine==0.21.0
django-cassandra-engine==0.2.1
djangotoolbox==1.6.2
futures==2.2.0
six==1.9.0
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Please help me understand and solve this issue.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was overlooked on my end - I'm fixing it now.  create_missing_keyspace would rarely "do the right thing", and it's very difficult and time consuming to fix a keyspace created with the wrong parameters.  You must now explicitly create a keyspace with the parameters you want.

Comment: So, I reinstall the package from source? From GitHub?

Comment: You need to create the keyspace manually using create_keyspace().  create_missing_keyspace argument on sync_table is gone.  I've updated the readme: https://github.com/cqlengine/cqlengine/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: The `create_missing_keyspace` is ignored in cqlengine 0.21, but not 0.20. Try a version < 0.21 of cqlengine or manual creation (see below).

Create a keyspace [like this](https://github.com/cqlengine/cqlengine/blob/0.21.0/cqlengine/management.py#L21e):

```
cqlengine.management.create_keyspace("cqlengine", replication_factor=1, strategy_class="SimpleStrategy")
```

The available strategies are [`SimpleStrategy`](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/cluster_architecture/replication#simplestrategy) and [`NetworkTopologyStrategy`](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/cluster_architecture/replication#networktopologystrategy).

I couldn't find updated docs for 0.21 so I checked [the source](https://github.com/cqlengine/cqlengine/blob/0.21.0/cqlengine/management.py#L21). Here's the declaration of `create_keyspace` in 0.21:

```
def create_keyspace(name, strategy_class, replication_factor, durable_writes=True, **replication_values):
    """
    creates a keyspace
    :param name: name of keyspace to create
    :param strategy_class: keyspace replication strategy class
    :param replication_factor: keyspace replication factor
    :param durable_writes: 1.2 only, write log is bypassed if set to False
    :param **replication_values: 1.2 only, additional values to ad to the replication data map
    """
```

Comment: Though the documentation shows the function takes only one argument `name`, I am getting this error:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    TypeError: create_keyspace() takes at least 3 arguments (1 given)

Comment: I also tried `sync_table(ExampleModel, create_missing_keyspace=True)`, but the same error arises. And the documentation says, `create_missing_keyspace=True` is default.

Comment: Yeah, I read some source now and the documentation is confusing. Especially since it's outdated :)

Comment: But its the same version!!!
They wouldn't change the source and let the docs remain unchanged, would they?

Comment: I guess that's why you should have at least the API reference automatically generated. Updating your documentation is easy to forget.

Comment: https://github.com/cqlengine/cqlengine/blob/master/cqlengine/management.py#L21
And
https://github.com/cqlengine/cqlengine/blob/master/cqlengine/management.py#L88

Comment: The `create_missing_keyspace` argument [was removed](https://github.com/cqlengine/cqlengine/commit/4bb8b313c0d684b286904cbe4ac962fdf73b5dd1) only two days ago. It's still there in the documentation however. I posted [an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/cqlengine/cqlengine/issues/323). It's still there in 0.20, so you might want to try that version.